# What does this red line across my shader node mean?

Tags: node-editor, interface

I am unsure what this red line linking the input and output of the node signifies in the below image.  Can anyone tell me what it is?

[image]

Answer (score 12):

That means the node is muted and isn't taking any part in calculations. To unmute it, select the node and press <kbd>M</kbd>

Comment: Thank you! I knew it'd be something simple - learn something new with Blender everyday!

Comment: It provides more information than "this node is muted": it says "this node is muted, and instead the value of the second input is being passed through."

Comment: Awesome, did not know we could mute and unmute!